# overwritting of contents in UItable View Cell in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

In my table view cell i need to display the contents of my array elements in a single cell and if i insert any new contents the previous contents are not to be overwritten.The previous content and my new content should be displayed in order.Here is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];


NSArray *arr=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:cnfqty,cnftitle,cnfrate, nil];

//cnfqty,cnftitle,cnfrate are NSString

finarray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[finarray addObjectsFromArray:arr];
NSLog(@"%@",finarray);


}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [finarray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    UILabel *lab=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 20)];
    lab.text=[finarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lab];

}
// Configure the cell...

return cell;
}
```

The problem which i'm facing with my code is each string is displayed in each cell and if i insert any new string previous contents are gone and only new contents are displayed.

To get clear idea about this question i'm trying to implement "add to cart" service for online shopping.As per concept the items have to be added from various products and it saves the product info and have to display the details in Table view.But i'm not getting it..

Kindly Guide please..Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3):

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

  ```
     UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[self.YourTableName dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];        
  if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
  }


      return cell; 
  }
  ```

  use ReusablecellIdentifier nil so it working correctly.....

Answer (score 1):

Your code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is a bit off.  You should be checking if the cell is nil before initializing it. Seems like you copied the brackets from somewhere, but left out the conditional.

Aside from that, you have no code to change the label of the cell for a cell being reused. You only set the text on new ones. One easy to to keep track of the label to reuse it is to give it a tag.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if(cell == nil)
  { // set up brand new cell
      cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
      UILabel *lab=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 20)];
      lab.tag = 150; // some int you can keep track of, possibly make it a define.
      [cell.contentView addSubview:lab];
  }
  // configure cell
  UILabel *cellLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:150]; // there's that tag again
  cellLabel.text = [finarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  return cell;
}
```

Comment: i tried it in another example by giving if(cell==nil) the cell images are repeated and that images load from my json file.So i followed by not using the condition..

Comment: You need to look at my answer and compare it to what you tried to see why what you tried was incorrect. 2 things can happen when requesting a cell: 1)create a brand new one, 2) reuse an existing one. Then after that, the views can be populated. Copy/paste this function over yours and it should work fine.

Comment: Same issue happens..all contents are displayed in each cell and a warning appears as incompatiable pointer type

Comment: see my edit to fix that warning, the view just needed to be cast to a label. What do you mean by "all contents are displayed in each cell"?

Comment: My 3 string values loads in each cell..but my need is all the string value need to display in one cell..i need to implement add to cart services.i think you are aware of that..

Comment: Your requirements are unfortunately unclear. You should outline what your data looks like and what you are trying to get this table to display.

Comment: My need is cnfqty, cnftitle, cnfrate have to be displayed in single cell.where if i pass another 3 string value with same string name it have to display in next cell.Have i explained you clear?

Comment: In that case, you only have data for a single cell. Is that correct? There is no data structure that holds a list of data for multiple cells as far as I can see.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14427/discussion-between-dany-and-dima)

Answer (score 1):

Make your "finarray" to store an array in each object (I mean you need a kind of bi-dimensional array). In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you will extract the array from `finarray` by the `indexPath.row`, and make a loop through the extracted array to populate your content. The first time each array in your finarray will contain only 1 object. By changing the content in the cell, you actually will add one more object into the array located at index of your edited cell. Then, by reloading data, the table will display the new added data. Make sure you manage the height of the rows for the edited cells,as they will need to be increased.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

//bla bla bla whatever you had here

NSMutableArray *arr1=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:cnfqty, nil];
NSMutableArray *arr2=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:cnftitle, nil];
NSMutableArray *arr3=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:cnfrate, nil];

NSMutableArray *arrMain=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:arr1, arr2, arr3, nil];


finarray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[finarray addObjectsFromArray:arr];

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

//bla bla bla the code to initiate the cell

NSArray *tmpArray = [finarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

for(int i = 0; i<tmpArray.count;i++){
  //create the label
  //set the frame, making sure that origin.y is multiplied by "i"
  //set label's text as [tmpArray objectAtIndex:i]
  //add the label to cell
}

return cell;
}
```

Comment: Can u please explain some brief..i got what you are saying but cant understand completely

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer but i need to display the 3 strings in same cell.How can i do that..

Comment: and also it overwrites my previous content..Is there any way to avoid that...I need to have my old contents..

Comment: @Dany, what,the heck, did not you understand? Do you see the label that is created in the "for" loop? you will have 100 objects in the sub-array, so 100 different labels will be shown in your cell, one under another,and they will look like 100 different strings in your cell

Comment: And,as I said, you willhave to define the cell's height, as you will be increasing the content in your cells, so return cellHeight*(indexPath.row+1) in your - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath, where "cellHeight"is the height of the rows you have set in your xib.

Comment: i did that before and assigned the value as -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    
    return 150.0;
    
}

Comment: this will make all cells to be 150.0, but you need to make 150.0 the cells with a single label, and 150.0 * x for the cells with x labels, as they will arrange one under another

Answer (score 1):

Not sure your cellForRowAtIndexPath is correct.  Looks like you are not checking to see if cell is nil.  If you are (somehow inside the brackets), then you seem to only be updating lab.text within that if(cell == nil) statement.

It should probably be something more like the following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ 
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UILabel *lab; 
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];  

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];      
        lab=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 20)];
        lab.tag = 1; // Really any arbitraty number
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lab];  
    }else{
        lab = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:1]
    }

    // Configure the cell... 
    lab.text=[finarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];      

    return cell; 
}
```

Comment: This code will not compile because `lab` will not exist in the case of a reused cell. Using tags to refer to reused cells solves this (see my answer).

Comment: But my label is declared inside if condition..i can't access it outside of loop...

Comment: @Dima - Good catch, I am used to having my code (with samples) available to me!  Was trying to answer without :-)  Thanks

Comment: @Dima - Not anymore.  Think this would be faster also (No allocation EACH time asking for a cell)!  This is also the more standard way presented on many sites.  Thanks for the catches.

Comment: It was but you edited it again. You're right except that it's not an allocation, just a pointer assignment.

Comment: @Dima - I think that was from a previous version of your answer maybe, or perhaps Im just seeing things LOL